# How to export the output of bitcoind JSON-RPC calls using bitcoin-ruby interface to a text file in tab-delimited format

Tags: ruby, bitcoin, json-rpc, bitcoind

I am running the bitcoind server in Ubuntu 16.04. Also using a method of connecting to bitcoind's RPC using bitcoin-ruby:

```
require 'bitcoin'
require 'net/http'
require 'json'
RPCUSER = "**"
RPCPASSWORD = "**"
HOST = "localhost"
PORT= 8332

def bitcoinRPC(method,param)
    http = Net::HTTP.new(HOST,PORT)
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new('/')
    request.basic_auth(RPCUSER,RPCPASSWORD)
    request.content_type = 'application/json'
    request.body = {method:method,params:param,id:'jsonrpc'}.to_json
    JSON.parse(http.request(request).body)["result"]
```

end

The following RPC commands shows the parsed data of block number 514641 :

```
bhash= 514641
bid= bitcoinRPC('getblockhash',[bhash])
bid="0000000000000000003b34a5f6cb571435b71449c38e54bf2cbafb7ca3800501"
blk= bitcoinRPC("getblock",[bid])
```

And the keys inside the blk variables are as follows:

```
blk.keys
["hash", "confirmations", "strippedsize", "size", "weight", "height", 
"version", "versionHex", "merkleroot", "tx", "time", "mediantime", "nonce", 
"bits", "difficulty", "chainwork", "previousblockhash", "nextblockhash"]
```

I want to parse the key values of "hash" , "tx", "time", "difficulty" from inside the block number 514641 calculating back to block number 1 using ruby programming and parse the output to a text file in tab-delimited following format:

```
hash     tx      time     difficulty
000...  12X....  2344556   5455345
 --     13X...      --     5678899
 --     14X...      --     6454545
```

Here, the "hash" and "time" will be same values for the same block. I am new to ruby programming. Any guideline will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `blk` object is just a ruby hash at this point so you should be able to just do:

```
keys = %w[hash tx time difficulty]  # array of strings (keys you want)
data = keys.map{|key| blk[key]} # array of data from the keys

require 'csv'
CSV.open("myfile.csv", "w") do |csv|
  csv << keys # keys will be header row of csv
  data.each{|d| csv << d} # loop over data and push into new row of csv
end
```

Comment: There was an error :Traceback (most recent call last):
        6: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
        5: from (irb):52
        4: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/csv.rb:1289:in `open'
        3: from (irb):54:in `block in irb_binding'
        2: from (irb):54:in `each'
        1: from (irb):54:in `block (2 levels) in irb_binding'
NoMethodError (undefined method `<' for #<CSV:0x0000557c853d7d70>
Did you mean?  <<)

Comment: @Rubz yep I had a typo, the error even told what it was.  I fixed it, see updated answer. Thanks.